# How to install jquery file jquery-latest.min.js?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a qwerty.html.erb. If I define jquery file as `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`it is work! But I install jquery file in assets/javascripts - it is not work. What needs define in my html.erb file that jquery is work?

I have in directory app/assets/javascripts following files:

```
application.js
jquery-latest.min.js
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-latest.min.js
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

**qwerty.html.erb**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Природа</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-latest.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-1.9.1.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="2SH+V2GfBlZyTnZVfptssDu/kfKiSrNRHpYnRbSPrE4=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>




<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><img alt="1" src="/assets/1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img alt="2" src="/assets/2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img alt="3" src="/assets/3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img alt="4" src="/images/4.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img alt="5" src="/images/5.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".slider").each(function () // обрабатываем каждый слайдер
        {
            var obj = $(this);
            $(obj).append("<div class='nav'></div>");
            $(obj).find("li").each(function ()
            {
                $(obj).find(".nav").append("<span rel='"+$(this).index()+"'></span>"); // добавляем блок навигации
                $(this).addClass("slider"+$(this).index());
            });
            $(obj).find("span").first().addClass("on"); // делаем активным первый элемент меню
        });
    });
    function sliderJS (obj, sl) // slider function
    {
        var ul = $(sl).find("ul"); // находим блок
        var bl = $(sl).find("li.slider"+obj); // находим любой из элементов блока
        var step = $(bl).width(); // ширина объекта
        $(ul).animate({marginLeft: "-"+step*obj}, 500); // 500 это скорость перемотки
    }
    $(document).on("click", ".slider .nav span", function() // slider click navigate
    {
        var sl = $(this).closest(".slider"); // находим, в каком блоке был клик
        $(sl).find("span").removeClass("on"); // убираем активный элемент
        $(this).addClass("on"); // делаем активным текущий
        var obj = $(this).attr("rel"); // узнаем его номер
        sliderJS(obj, sl); // слайдим
        return false;
    });
</script>

<style>
    .slider {
        z-index: 9;
        width: 700px;
        height: 290px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 0 7px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .slider ul,
    .slider li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .slider ul {
        width: 9999px;
    }
    .slider ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
        width: 700px;
        height: 290px;
    }
    .slider .nav {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        bottom: 12px;
    }
    .slider .nav span {
        opacity: 0.9;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
    }
    .slider .nav span.on {
        background: #2e9419;
    }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that version of jQuery - Rails comes with its own known-compatible version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put your js file in vendor\assets\components\jquery\ folder
- Add next line to your app\assets\javascript\application.js

  ```
  //= require jquery\jquery-latest.min.js
  ```

Comment: share the source code of your generated page, please

Comment: and I have no directory vendor\assets\components... What needs write in qwerty.html.erb file?

Comment: Nothing! Rails gets all information from application.js. Here is more detaled information http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Remove this line from your *.erb file <script type="javascript" src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script> and provide the HTML code of <b>generated</b> page. This directory ( vendor\assets\components) you must create manually.

Comment: "provide the HTML code of <b>generated</b> page." Sorry, I don't understand. For example?

Comment: Rails generate HTML page and you can view it in the browser. Can I look at this HTML ?

Comment: As I see Rail includes jQuery to HTML: <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-latest.min.js?body=1"></script> (it is from your code). You can check it by opening the page "http:\\yourdomain\assets\jquery-latest.min.js?body=1 You have too much of jQuery versions included to your page and I recommended you to fix it.